# AWS Cognito - Use Refresh Token immediately after login

Tags: javascript, amazon-cognito, refresh-token

I want to force-refresh the AWS cognito token in the client, so that as soon as a user logs in the app immediately uses the refresh token to get a new access token (with longer exp time). I've read about [initiateAuth](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_InitiateAuth.html) and cognitoUser.refreshSession() methods, but I'm not sure which one I need to use? I'm trying the below method and I am getting a new token back but it's always just valid for 1 more hour (at least that is what I see when I check the exp time on the token). I want to get a token that is valid for 30 days (which is what I have configured in cognito). Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```js
 
  const getTokens = function(session) {
    return {
      accessToken: session.getAccessToken(),
      idToken: session.getIdToken(),
      refreshToken: session.getRefreshToken()
 };
  
  cognitoUser.refreshSession(refreshToken, (err, session) => {
  if (err) {
   console.log(err);
  } else {
        const tokens = getTokens(session);
   console.log(tokens);
      localStorage.setItem("sessionTokens", JSON.stringify(tokens));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

*The ID and Access token in Cognito are valid for 1 hour and this is not configurable. You mentioned you have configured the tokens to last for 30 days, this is the validity/expiry time of your refresh tokens.
Calling certain methods on the client side SDKs (Amplify or identity SDK) will automatically check the validity and expiry time of the tokens and refresh them if needed.*

This has now changed as can be seen here:
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/08/amazon-cognito-user-pools-supports-customization-of-token-expiration/

Answer (score 0):

Cognito recently added options to configure the token validity.

- Refresh tokens can have a TTL from 60 minutes to 365 days.
- ID tokens and Access tokens can have a TTL from 5 minutes to 1 day

just look in the details of your user pool app client, the new fields are in there for easy configuration.